# How to write an if statement where conditions can be variable in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement

I want to write an if statement.
For e.g.

```
if first == a and second == b and third == c and fourth == d:
   # code
```

The problem is that the value of a, b, c, d, e can be None. In that case that particular condition should not be evaluated.

For e.g. if b = None then the if condition becomes:

```
if first == a and third == c and fourth == d:
   # code
```

How do I implement this in python? Can someone please help?

Comment: `if(first = a, second = b, third = c, fourth = d)` If your intention is to _compare_ these values, then you should use `==`, not `=`.  `==` is **comparison**.  `=` is **assignment**.  Also you can't really use commas in an `if` like this, so it's unclear exactly what you're trying to do with the commas.  Should they be `and`? 
 Should they be `or`?   Also, `if` does not require surrounding parentheses, so why are they here?  Again, confusion.

Comment: @JohnGordon Sorry my mistake I have corrected now.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Okay I made a few syntax errors which I have corrected now. I think now you should understand it.

Comment: @mkrieger1 The problem is that the value of a, b, c, d, e can be None. In that case those particular conditions should not be evaluated.

For e.g. if b = None and d = None then the if condition becomes:
if first == a and third == c:
   # code
I do not care what is the value of a and c al long as they are not None.

Comment: On what line do you get your error? Because I suspect it has nothing to do with your original question.

Comment: What's a `QuerySet`?

Comment: @MatBailie The if condition.

Comment: @Samwise A QuerySet is a collection of data from a database. A QuerySet is built up as a list of objects

Answer (score 2):

I might do this with an `all`:

```
if all(x is None or x == y for x, y in (
    (first, a),
    (second, b),
    (third, c),
    (fourth, d),
)):
    # etc
```

which is just a shorter way of writing:

```
if ((first is None or first == a)
    and (second is None or second == b)
    and (third is None or third == c)
    and (fourth is None or fourth == d)
):
    # etcj
```

The important thing is that you want to combine a bunch of `or` conditions (`first is None or first == a`) to form a large `and` condition (which is what `all` does with an iterable).

Note that if instead of four variables `first` thru `fourth` and four variables `a` thru `d` you have two lists:

```
spam = [first, second, third, fourth]
eggs = [a, b, c, d]
```

you can write:

```
if all(x is None or x == y for x, y in zip(spam, eggs)):
    # etc
```

Comment: I am getting this error argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable.

Comment: You don't say what specifically got you that error, but I'm going to guess you wanted to try the `zip` thing with all `None` values but instead of `spam = [None, None, None, None]` you did `spam = None`. 
 Did I guess right?

Comment: @Samwise The code is already written in the edit part of the question. It is - if ((first is None or first == a)
    and (second is None or second == b)
    and (third is None or third == c)
    and (fourth is None or fourth == d)
):

Comment: There's no function being called in that code, much less one that expects an iterable.  So that isn't the line of code that's producing your error.  You should update your question to include the actual code you're running and the full error (including stack trace).

Comment: @Samwise Please see the question now I have made some edits.

Answer (score 0):

If first/second/third/fourth and a/b/c/d are list elements instead of individual variables, I think this will work:

```
all(lhs[i] == rhs[i] for i in range(len(lhs)) if rhs[i] is not None)
```

Where `lhs` is the list of [first, second, third, fourth] and `rhs` is the list of [a, b, c, d]

How should the edge case be handled where a/b/c/d are *all* None?

Comment: In that case there won't be any condition. Like if True:

Answer (score -1):

I think Samwise's solution is the best one. The most trivial, perhaps ugliest, way of doing what you want could be:

```
if (a is None or first == a) and (b is None or second == b) and (c is None or third == c) and (d is None or fourth == d):
```